# Viterbi Decoder=1/2 k=4

Tags: matlab, dsp-core, viterbi-algorithm

Woud anyone have a viterbi decoding tool or c-code or .m file for (R=1/2, K=4)? 
I am trying to decode a bitstream received in RFSTUDIO from a non-TI transceiver and it says that it uses this kind of coding.
Regards 
Vangelis

Comment: Requests for code are off-topic here.